# C# - How to handle similar data types when dealing with APIs

Tags: c#, rest

It is so frustrating dealing with some APIs when they use all kinds of different styles for property names.  It causes me to create so many different models for the same type of data.  I'm wondering if there is a best practice for handling this type of scenario.

I start out calling an API and I get back a list of:

```
{
  "firstName": <value>
}
```

Then I want to add one of these widgets to a scheduler but it requires me to send a dateTime stamp so I have to send this in a post which means I have to create a new model even though it's only one additional property

```
{
   "firstName": <value>
   "dateUpdated": <date>
}
```

This api now sends me back a list of similar types like this(but with underscores):

```
{
  "user_name": <value>
  "date_updated": <value>
}
```

Then later I receive data like this

```
{
   "UserName": <value>
   "DateUpdated": <value>
}
```

It is so frustrating because I have to create all these different models all the time.  Not to mention I have to constantly convert from one to another and I end up with conversion code like this all over the place in my services:

```
var tempWidget = new Widget(){
  firstName = returnedWidget.FirstName,
  dateUpdated = returnedWidget.DateUpdated
}
return tempWidget
```

Comment: Then you should be a little more abstract. Have you thought about using a `Dictionary<string, object>` instead of creating all these models? The json serializer will handle serialization for you..

Comment: Adopt an Enterprise Service Bus (ESB) with a _canonical data model_ and _data transformation service_ on the service's endpoint

Answer (score 0):

You can use JObject Class from Newtonsoft.Json.Linq to get rid of many models.

Answer (score 0):

You could try making one model and multiple interfaces for the fields you need.  You still have the interfaces but adding that is much lighter than touching your model and you retain a single location for all fields.  You also keep intellisense, which you may not with serializations.

```
public class ViewModel {
    public string user_name {get;set;}
    public date date_updated {get;
    public string firstName {get;set;}
}

public interface IUserAndDate {
    string user_name {get;set;}
    date date_updated {get;set;}    
}

public interface IFirstName{
    string firstName {get;set;}
}
```

Your methods can then receive an IFirstname or IUserAndDate as appropriate and they'll be cast as such.

```
public void myhelper(IUserAndDate userandDate) {
   ....
}

someObject.myhelper(viewModel);
```

This is kind of hiding the issue, but it's almost as good as getting a custom class per permutation.  I would caution against overuse though.

You could also explore an adapter pattern, in which case you could model the data coming in and normalize it into a singular model.  You'd still probably need viewmodels to store the pre-transformed data anyway though.